# Get most recent datetime column with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple class that mirrors a SQLite table.

```
class SyncAudit
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string SyncTime { get; set; }
    public int Successful { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to construct a LINQ method that returns the most recent sync time.

```
    public string getLastSyncTime()
    {
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
        {
            var query = db.Table<SyncAudit>()
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.SyncTime)
                .Select(c => c.SyncTime)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            return query.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to find the most recent synctime in the SQLite database and return it as a string.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Using: https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net

Comment: this looks fine, what's the problem? is `SyncTime` really a `string` in the database, or should it be a `DateTime`?

Comment: You don't get a `MissingMethodException` with the code shown.

Comment: It's the error I'm getting. However, changing the model to DateTime fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SyncTime` is a string in your model but seems to be (or should be) a `DateTime`. So fix that in the database. If that's not possible you have to parse it:

```
DateTime lastSyncTime = db.Table<SyncAudit>().AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the processing in memory
    .Select(c => DateTime.Parse(c.SyncTime))
    .OrderByDescending(dt => dt)
    .FirstOrDefault();
return lastSyncTime;
```